# Django include html without parsing template tags

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I'm creating a Django based web app which is server-side rendered. However there are now a few pages I would like to re-render using javascript from a feed.

I would prefer to use a DRY approach and re-use my existing Django templates, include them onto the page inside  tags.

Then I can use the template library of my choice (there are many that support Django templates)

- JinjaJS https://github.com/ericclemmons/jinja.js
- JinjaJS II https://github.com/sstur/jinja-js
- Swig http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/
- Plate https://github.com/chrisdickinson/plate
- TwigJS https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js

However i'm stuck on the simplest thing, include the template without parsing! Here are my attempted approaches which don't work

**Expected output**

```
<ul>
    <li>John Doe</a></li>
    <li>Sally Taylor</a></li>
    <li>David Smith</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/template">
    <ul>
    {% for person in people %}
        <li>{{ person.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</script>
```

**Approach 1** - works but I have to repeat the same html twice

index.html

```
{% include "includes/list.html" %}
<script type="text/template">
    {% include "includes/list.html" with script=1 %}
</script>
```

list.html

```
{% if script = 1 %}
{% verbatim %}
    <ul>
        {% for person in people %}
            <li>{{ person.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
{% else %}
<ul>
    {% for person in people %}
        <li>{{ person.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Approach 2** - doesn't output after it reaches for loop

index.html

```
{% include "includes/list.html" %}
<script type="text/template">
    {% include_raw "includes/list.html" %}
</script>
```

tags.py

```
from django import template
from django.template import loader, Context

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def include_raw(templatename):
    return loader.get_template(templatename).render(Context())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `{% if script = 1 %}` should be `{% if script == 1 %}`

Comment: That method works correctly, but it means I have to repeat my html twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it using this solution:
https://gist.github.com/HenrikJoreteg/742160

The code to make it work was:

index.html

```
{% load pages_tags %}
{% include "includes/list.html" %}
<script type="text/template">
    {% raw_include "includes/list.html" %}
</script>
```

list.html

```
<ul>
    {% for person in people %}
        <li>{{ person.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

pages_tags.py

```
from django import template, conf
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def raw_include(path):
    import os.path

    for template_dir in conf.settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS:
        filepath = '%s/%s' % (template_dir, path)
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            break

    fp = open(filepath, 'r')
    output = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    return output
```

Here is an example project showing it all working together, including rendering the client-side templates with JavaScript:

https://github.com/kmturley/django-client-templates

And I also made this jsperf to test the performance of different jinja style templating libraries:

https://jsperf.com/jinja-client-side-libraries/5